# Unable to setRawMode in a nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

Initially I tried to set raw mode using `tty.setRawMode(true)` the log told me that was deprecated and I should be using `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)` but that command is giving me `TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'setRawMode'` I cant seem to find much else in the way of raw mode documentation that suggests any other apporoaches anyone know how to get this working?

I am using version 0.10.25

Comment: Check the result of process.stdin.isTTY. If it is false, node is not running in a TTY context and process.stdin will not be a TTY.readStream

Comment: To find out why this is, I need more information on how you are running your program. Are you using `child_process` perhaps?

Comment: How would I go about checking that? I ran it with no result and `console.log` returns undefined. No child process.

Comment: Let me rephrase: when you execute node, are you running a script or using the repl? Are you on Windows or Linux? Any information would help (console.log always returns undefined). Node is likely unable to detect that it is being run from a terminal, so I need more information about your environment to help.

Comment: I meant I ran `console.log(process.stdin.isTTY)` and got undefined. Am running linux no repl, am running it through terminal with `node myscript.js` `stdout.write` works fine so standard in/out seems to be the console.

Comment: Once again, `console.log` always returns undefined. Does it print anything out? My guess is that you are redirecting stdin somehow, but perhaps someone else can be of more help.

Comment: if I run `console.log('foo bar')` that is not undefined...yes it prints out the word undefined to the terminal. Interesting note if I `console.log(process.stdin)`  `_connecting:` is `false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81035/discussion-between-dylan-mackenzie-and-jake).

Answer (score 5):

It works wonderfully via **node server.js** but **nodemon server.js** gives me `TypeError: process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function` error and the server aborts.

Since **nodemon** is also waiting for keys to be pressed (i.e. "rs" to restart server), we're running into a conflict because **nodemon** has commandeered `process.stdin`.

To workaround the issue, I added a **config.ini** directive named `nodemonMode=yes|no`.  If it is set to yes, then I skip the offending section of code with the `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)` code in it.  I bet there's is even a simpler way to determine if you're running **nodemon**.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out nodemon uses child_process, because of this writing `process.stdin.setRawMode(true);` in a script that you then run with nodemon will result in `TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'setRawMode'`.